# How to group, sort and calculate difference in this pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, diff

I created this dataframe and need to group my data into category with the same number of beds, city, baths and sort(descending) each elements in the group by price. 
Secondly I need to find the difference between each price with the one ranked after into the same group.
For example the result should be like that:

1 bed, 1 bath, Madrid, 10

1 bed, 1 bath, Madrid, 8

1 bed, 1 bath, Madrid, 5

1 bed, 1 bath, Madrid, 1

I should get 2, 3, 4...

I tried some code it seems far than what I expect to find...

```
data=[[1,'paris',1,2,'10'],[2,'madrid',2,2,8],[3,'madrid',2,2,11],[4,'paris',1,2,6],[5,'paris',1,2,5],[6,'madrid',2,1,7],[7,'paris',2,1,7],[8,'paris',2,1,7],[9,'madrid',1,4],[10,'paris',2,1,3],[11,'madrid',2,2,7],[12,'paris',2,3,12],[13,'madrid',2,3,7],[14,'madrid',1,1,3],[15,'paris',1,1,3],[16,'madrid',1,1,4],[17,'paris',1,1,5]]

df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id','city','beds','baths','price'])
df

df['gap'] = df.sort_values('price',ascending=False).groupby(['city','beds','baths'])['price'].diff()
print (df)
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: why is the first price a string and not an int?

Comment: `[9,'madrid',1,4]` this part of your `data` list of list has no price. Pandas will change it to NaN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors = 'coerce'` 
to get rid of the strings in the `price` column, I would then calculate the difference without taking into account those **rooms whose price is unknown** (using [`DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)). Then I show the result ordering in DataFrame and without ordering:

```
df['price']=pd.to_numeric(df['price'],errors = 'coerce')
```

---

```
df['difference_price'] = ( df.dropna()
                             .sort_values('price',ascending=False)
                             .groupby(['city','beds','baths'])['price'].diff(-1) )
```

or using [`GroupBy.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html):

```
df['difference_price'] = df['price'].sub( df.dropna()
                                            .sort_values('price',ascending=False)
                                            .groupby(['city','beds','baths'])
                                            .price
                                            .shift(-1) )
```

---

**Display result**

```
print(df,'\n'*3,'Sorted DatFrame: ')
print(df.sort_values(['city','beds','baths','price'],ascending = [True,True,True,False]))
```

**Output**

```
    id    city  beds  baths  price  difference_price
0    1   paris     1      2   10.0               4.0
1    2  madrid     2      2    8.0               1.0
2    3  madrid     2      2   11.0               3.0
3    4   paris     1      2    6.0               1.0
4    5   paris     1      2    5.0               NaN
5    6  madrid     2      1    7.0               NaN
6    7   paris     2      1    7.0               0.0
7    8   paris     2      1    7.0               4.0
8    9  madrid     1      4    NaN               NaN
9   10   paris     2      1    3.0               NaN
10  11  madrid     2      2    7.0               NaN
11  12   paris     2      3   12.0               NaN
12  13  madrid     2      3    7.0               NaN
13  14  madrid     1      1    3.0               NaN
14  15   paris     1      1    3.0               NaN
15  16  madrid     1      1    4.0               1.0
16  17   paris     1      1    5.0               2.0 


 Sorted DatFrame: 
    id    city  beds  baths  price  difference_price
15  16  madrid     1      1    4.0               1.0
13  14  madrid     1      1    3.0               NaN
8    9  madrid     1      4    NaN               NaN
5    6  madrid     2      1    7.0               NaN
2    3  madrid     2      2   11.0               3.0
1    2  madrid     2      2    8.0               1.0
10  11  madrid     2      2    7.0               NaN
12  13  madrid     2      3    7.0               NaN
16  17   paris     1      1    5.0               2.0
14  15   paris     1      1    3.0               NaN
0    1   paris     1      2   10.0               4.0
3    4   paris     1      2    6.0               1.0
4    5   paris     1      2    5.0               NaN
6    7   paris     2      1    7.0               0.0
7    8   paris     2      1    7.0               4.0
9   10   paris     2      1    3.0               NaN
11  12   paris     2      3   12.0               NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly with:

> group my data into category with the same number of beds, city, baths and sort(descending)

All data that does not fulfill the value should be deleted? (Where beds and baths are different). This is my code to provide an answer given your problem:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd     
data=[[1,'paris',1,2,'10'],[2,'madrid',2,2,8],[3,'madrid',2,2,11],[4,'paris',1,2,6],[5,'paris',1,2,5],[6,'madrid',2,1,7],[7,'paris',2,1,7],[8,'paris',2,1,7],[9,'madrid',1,4],[10,'paris',2,1,3],[11,'madrid',2,2,7],[12,'paris',2,3,12],[13,'madrid',2,3,7],[14,'madrid',1,1,3],[15,'paris',1,1,3],[16,'madrid',1,1,4],[17,'paris',1,1,5]]

df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id','city','beds','baths','price'])

df_new = df[df['beds'] == df['baths']]
df_new = df_new.sort_values(['city','price'],ascending=[False,False]).reset_index(drop=True)
df_new['diff_price'] = df_new.groupby(['city','beds','baths'])['price'].diff(-1)
print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
   id    city  beds  baths price diff_price
0  17   paris     1      1     5        NaN
1  15   paris     1      1     3         -2
2   3  madrid     2      2    11        NaN
3   2  madrid     2      2     8         -3
4  11  madrid     2      2     7         -1
5  16  madrid     1      1     4        NaN
6  14  madrid     1      1     3         -1
```

Comment: The code looks good with diff(-1), thank you for the help. I keep the data that does not fulfill with the value.

Comment: I'll edit my answer with the `-1` and you can accept it if it helps you solve the problem :) Thanks!